# Spell checker in a WPF RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I have created a `RichTextBox` text editor as a c# Form application solution. I have added a WPF application to this solution to act as a spellchecker. Basically, when I run the spell checker the contents of the `RichTextBox` are copied to a WPF `RichTextBox` in the WPF application which I have configured to look like a spell check dialog. I have included a `ListBox` which displays the spelling error suggestions and buttons that allow the user to ignore errors or change if one of the suggestions are clicked.

The main routine loops through the text in the RichTextBox until it finds a spelling error. The user then has the option to ignore by clicking a button that calls `EditingCommands.IgnoreSpellingError` or change by clicking a button that calls `EditingCommands.CorrectSpellingError`. Currently I am using another button to then re-cycle through the `RichTextBox` to find the next spelling error.

Ideally what I would like to happen is, for example, when the ignore button is clicked, the `EditingCommands.IgnoreSpellingError` is called and then the main routine is run immediately after, like so:

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        button3.Command = EditingCommands.IgnoreSpellingError;
        button3.CommandTarget = richTextBox1;
        spellCheckWords();
    }
```

However, this does not work as the `RichTextBox` seems to go out of synchronisation with the spell checker. It's as if the form or the `RichTextBox` are not refreshing properly. Just to re-iterate, if I use a separate button to re-run the main routine then it works ok.

The full **code** is below.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.IO;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        richTextBox1.SpellCheck.IsEnabled = true;
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.Paste();
        richTextBox1.ContextMenu = GetContextMenu();
        spellCheckWords();
    }

    private static int chrPos = 0;

    private void spellCheckWords()
    {
        SpellingError spellingError;
        TextRange spellErrorRange;
        TextPointer start_pointer, end_pointer;

        richTextBox1.ContextMenu = GetContextMenu();
        richTextBox1.SelectAll();
        int txtLen = richTextBox1.Selection.Text.Length;
        bool noSpellingErrors = true; ;

        for (int i = chrPos; i < txtLen; i++)
        {
            start_pointer = richTextBox1.Document.ContentStart.GetNextInsertionPosition
                (LogicalDirection.Forward).GetPositionAtOffset(i, LogicalDirection.Forward);

            spellingError = richTextBox1.GetSpellingError(start_pointer);
            if (spellingError != null)
            {
                 spellErrorRange = richTextBox1.GetSpellingErrorRange(start_pointer);
                int errRange = spellErrorRange.Text.Length;

                textBox1.Text = spellErrorRange.Text;

                noSpellingErrors = true;
                string textRun = start_pointer.GetTextInRun(LogicalDirection.Forward);
                string trimmedString = string.Empty;
                end_pointer = richTextBox1.Document.ContentStart.GetNextInsertionPosition
                    (LogicalDirection.Forward).GetPositionAtOffset(i + errRange, LogicalDirection.Forward);
                richTextBox1.Selection.Select(start_pointer, start_pointer);
                richTextBox1.Focus();

                Rect screenPos = richTextBox1.Selection.Start.GetCharacterRect(LogicalDirection.Forward);
                double offset = screenPos.Top + richTextBox1.VerticalOffset;
                richTextBox1.ScrollToVerticalOffset(offset - richTextBox1.ActualHeight / 2);

                listBox1.Items.Clear();
                foreach (string str in spellingError.Suggestions)
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(str);
                }
                //chrPos = i + errRange + 1;
                return;
            }
        }
        if (noSpellingErrors == true) 
        { 
            textBox1.Text = "No spelling Errors";
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            button2.IsEnabled = false;
            button3.IsEnabled = false;
            button4.IsEnabled = false;
            button6.IsEnabled = false;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.SelectAll();
        richTextBox1.Copy();
        richTextBox1.Document.Blocks.Clear();
        richTextBox1.SpellCheck.IsEnabled = false;
        this.Close();
    }

    private ContextMenu GetContextMenu()
    {
        return null;
    }

    private void listBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox1.SelectedItem != null)
            textBox1.Text = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        button2.Command = EditingCommands.CorrectSpellingError;
        button2.CommandParameter = textBox1.Text;
        button2.CommandTarget = richTextBox1;
        spellCheckWords();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        button3.Command = EditingCommands.IgnoreSpellingError;
        button3.CommandTarget = richTextBox1;
        spellCheckWords();
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        spellCheckWords();
    }


}
```

}

Comment: Can you please explain your issue in a little more detail ?

Comment: Hi Aviral, I'm not sure how to further explain this. That was one of the reasons why I included the code. If you could tell me what more you need to know I will respond. Bear in mind I am a relative newcomer to c#. David

Comment: Just one thing,what do you mean by `RichTextBox seems to go out of synchronisation with the spell checker`,what actually happens ?

Answer (score 0):

After a while i got your problem^^ (i think) and it is easy to fix.

In you Button-Click-events you set the command of the button and the parameters and then execute spellCheckWords. But the actual command is executed AFTER the code has leaved the method. 
Which means, spellCheckWords() is executed BEFORE IgnoreSpellingError.

Change your code to this:

```
        private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        EditingCommands.CorrectSpellingError.Execute(textBox1.Text, richTextBox1);
        spellCheckWords();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        EditingCommands.IgnoreSpellingError.Execute(null, richTextBox1);
        spellCheckWords();
    }
```

This will execute the command first and then the spellcheck again.

Comment: Worked a treat so thank you very much. Out of interest what was going wrong and how did this fix it?

Comment: When you set button.Command you actually don't execute the command you set it for later. Then spellCheckWords is execute and after the Click-Event is finished the Button recognize the command and execute it.

Comment: Hi Uwe, I now realise it only part worked. The ignore button works ok but the correct button does not. It does not change the text on the RichTextBox to the correct spelling.

Comment: It works in my example app. The text in the RichTextBox is replaced with the text from textBox1. Did you change the text in the TextBox? or do you want the text from somewhere else?

Comment: Hi Uwe, got it to work, didn't spot that textBox1.text was included in the  CorrectSpellingError.Execute part. My mistake.